# How to init a struct var with Data in swift3

Tags: swift3

I have a struct like this

```
struct Str{

let item1: UINT16
let item2: UINT16
let item3: UINT32

}
```

---

I got a struct var mystr

```
var mystr = Str(item1: 0x0101, item2: 0xffff, item3: 4)
```

And I've store the struct var into a Data var

```
var myData = Data(bytes: &mystr, count:MemoryLayout<Str>.size)
```

My question is how to use the Data var to initialize a new Str var(store the value of the Data into the struct)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not enough of an expert to tell how dangerous just dumping some memory to a `Data` object and then using that memory to init a struct is, but here is what you could do:

```
let strFromData = myData.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<Str>) -> Str in
    return p.pointee
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
let strFromData2 = myData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee as Str }
```

What I have done in former projects is to process a struct's members one by one:

```
extension Data
{
    mutating func append<T>(value: T)
    {
        var v = value
        self.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &v, count: 1))
    }
}

var data = Data()
data.append(value: mystr.item1)
data.append(value: mystr.item2)
data.append(value: mystr.item3)
```

Building a `Str` from `myData` using `Str`'s initializer:

```
let strFromData3 = myData.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> Str in
    let item1 = p[0]
    let item2 = p[1]
    let p2 = UnsafeRawPointer(p).bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 2)
    let item3 = p2[1]
    return Str(item1: item1, item2: item2, item3: item3)
}
```